# display: inline; doesn't work with copy link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zeroclipboard

Can you explain me why only the third "copy link" works only if all panels are closed ?
I want my copy link works when it's in a panel and when a panel is open too.

HERE IS MY PAGE: 
http://500milligrammes.com/facticemagazine/final/0/

**[JSFIDDLE](http://www.jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/4x3qctno/)**

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--[if IE 8]><html lang="en" class="lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!-->
<html lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>

    <style>
        .panel1,
        .panel2 {
            display: none;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            background-color: #eee
        }

        .flip1,
        .flip2 {
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            background-color: #eee
        }

        #check,
        #check2 {
            visibility: hidden;
            width: 12px;
            height: 12px;
        }

        span#copy-callbacks,
        span#copy-callbacks2 {
            float: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("span#copy-callbacks").zclip({
                path: "ZeroClipboard.swf",
                copy: $('#callback-paragraph').text(),
                beforeCopy: function() {
                    $('#copy-callbacks').css('background', 'none');
                },
                afterCopy: function() {
                    $('#copy-callbacks').css('background', 'none');
                }
            });

            document.getElementById("copy-callbacks").onclick = function() {
                document.getElementById("check").style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        });


        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('span#copy-callbacks').hover(
                function() {
                    $(this).css({
                        "color": "#e0ccb4"
                    });
                },

                function() {
                    $(this).css({
                        "color": "#000"
                    });
                }
            );




            $("span#copy-callbacks2").zclip({
                path: "ZeroClipboard.swf",
                copy: $('#callback-paragraph2').text(),
                beforeCopy: function() {
                    $('#copy-callbacks2').css('background', 'none');
                },
                afterCopy: function() {
                    $('#copy-callbacks2').css('background', 'none');
                }
            });

            document.getElementById("copy-callbacks2").onclick = function() {
                document.getElementById("check2").style.visibility = "visible";
            }
        });


        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('span#copy-callbacks2').hover(
                function() {
                    $(this).css({
                        "color": "#e0ccb4"
                    });
                },

                function() {
                    $(this).css({
                        "color": "#000"
                    });
                }
            );




            $(".flip1").click(function() {
                $(".panel1").slideToggle("fast");
            });

            $(".flip2").click(function() {
                $(".panel2").slideToggle("fast");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>





    <div class="flip1">Click to slide the first panel down or up</div>
    <div class="panel1">

        when this panel is open, any copy link works !!!

    </div>





    <div style="margin-top:150px;" class="flip2">Click to slide the second panel down or up</div>
    <div class="panel2">
        when a copy link is inside a panel, it doesn't work !!!
        <br/>
        <br/>

        <span id="copy-callbacks">Copy link&nbsp;&nbsp;<img  src="check.png" id="check" style="display: inline;"></span>
        <span style="font-size:0px;" id="callback-paragraph">essaie sans alert</span>

    </div>





    <div style="margin-top:150px; ">
        This one works perfectly when all panels are closed !!
        <br/>
        <span id="copy-callbacks2">Copy link&nbsp;&nbsp;<img  src="check.png" id="check2" style="display: inline;"></span>
        <span style="font-size:0px;" id="callback-paragraph2">essaie sans alert</span>
    </div>





    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.zclip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cbpFWSlider.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZClip adds an absolutely positioned flash (swf) object which clings to the bottom and when your panels are closed the zclip object container covers the third link and you can't click on it. 
See your updated fiddle, I put a border around zclip and you can see that it's right over the link: **http://jsfiddle.net/4x3qctno/2/**

When you open panels it pushes third link down, but the zclip container stays in the same place and so your link works then.

To fix this, change z-index of zclip object container in CSS like so:

```
.zclip{
    z-index:-1000!important;
}
```

Comment: thanks guy, you help me a lot, effectively the position was the problem. to resolve this problem, i worked on query.zclip.js -> i change position absolution by inherit and delete line about top and left px :D

Comment: Yeah, you can do that too. There are several ways, z-index is the simpliest. Use code inspector in the future to highlight elements and see what's where. Positioned elements covering other elements is a common problem...

Comment: just a question, what about the copy link inside a panel, why we can't see the border:1px solid red; ?

Comment: have you an idea about my previous comment ?

Comment: Sorry, missed this. Link inside the panel works in jsFiddle. There is only one zclip object on the page. That's why you only see one red border...

Comment: no in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4x3qctno/2/ -> my second panel have a copy link inside

Comment: Ok, yes I see the link, what's wrong with it? It seems to work. I can click on it...

Comment: In fact when you click on the panel, it works fine, but the problem is that the copy link doesn't have a red border. so the copy link doesn't work !!!